# Complex condition for new column in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

In Power Query (M) there is a table with columns A and B. Column C is generated. Column C get value "T" if: A < 3 and the value of B exists elsewhere in column B where A is >= 3. This is true for the 4th row.

Furthermore, to complete it:

- if column A >= 3 then column C = column B
- if column A < 3 and NOT
  (the value of B exists elsewhere in column B where A is >= 3) then
  "n"

Is there a (simple) way to write this in M?

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | x | x |
| 3 | x | x |
| 3 | x | x |
| **1** | **x** | **T** |
| 2 | y | n |
| 2 | y | n |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: here is the extra information:

if column A >= 3 then column C = column B,
if column A < 3   and NOT (the value of B exists elsewhere in column B where A is >= 3) then "n"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**
You can use this

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source,"C",(i)=>
    if i[A]>=3 then i[B] else if 
    i[A]<3 and Table.RowCount(
        Table.SelectRows(Source, each [B]=i[B] and [A]>=3)
    ) >1 then "T" else "n"
)
in #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: ´´else [B]´´ seems does not fit on the sample 2

Comment: not sure what that means. I am not using else [B] because else [B] does not fit the pattern. I left it as a null

Comment: first 3 rows fits the pattern where else [B] but last two rows does not fit ... and i need to learn how to use (i)=> function in the codes... )))

Comment: OK, well, I agree. The sample data did not seem to have a pattern. i[Column] is the value of the current row for that column in the current table, while [Column] is any row in the 2nd table for that Column. So i[Column]=[Column] finds a row in the 2nd table that matches the current row from 1st table